# Changing Screen Orientation during runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Start-Menu scene, which I want to be shown in the Portrait Orientation. The rest of the game is in the standard landscape orientation.

I've tried following in the scenes init method:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

and

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

My question is, how can I switch Screen-Orientations during runtime?

thanks in advance!
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code in the view controller you want to be in landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

That code will force the view controller to only display in landscape-left. You return whichever orientations you want to support.

e.g.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
```

I know you are using cocos2d but this code should still work fine in your view controller.

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to support autorotation...I just want one specific scene to be in the Portrait Orientation...if you rotate the device nothing should happen

Comment: If you use the first block of code I posted that is the only orientation that will be supported in that view. It won't be able to rotate to any other orientation.

Comment: This would only work if your start sequence was in a different view controller than the landscape part of the app.

Comment: I have a standard Cocos2D project setup with a single view controller

Comment: Ok, now I see this won't work. I haven't really used cocos2d so I didn't realise it was all within one view controller. If the landscape and portrait parts were in separate view controllers my approach should work.

Comment: thx anyway...might come in handy someday, marked your answer as "useful" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing something directly I. cocos2d. But you can put everything in a single UIView and then do a 90 degrees rotation transform on it. There is a private API to force rotate the device but it is agains app store rules to use it and it can be unpredictable too.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You know you are in landscape mode, and you want to show a single screen in portrait right? When you push the screen on it should already be in portrait? Do you want to show a rotation animation? All of this is possible by manually rotating the view. There is no reason to "force rotate" the device.

Comment: I have a standard Cocos2D project and I've specified in the AppDelegate to run with the my StartMenu scene (which is supposed to be in a Portrait Orientation) then, if you click say "play, levels, or whatever" it goes into a landscape orientation.